# Using JWT -- on the server-side is there a way to check if a user is currently logged in?

Tags: express, session, push-notification, notifications, jwt

When using JWT for user authentication, is there any way server-side to decide if one or more users are currently logged in?

The use case I have at hand is for sending out push notifications -- where I want to only send notifications to users who are currently logged in.

Comment: I think you can check if the token is valid

Comment: but I don't have the token on the server -- since it's saved client side

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Since the server is initiating the process of checking if user is **currently** connected, you need something similar to [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). You can use for example [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/)

## Explanation

1. Establish a two way communication channel between the client and the server.
2. On the server maintain a list of all session IDs of clients **currently** connected. If a client has logged out, remove the corresponding ID
3. When you want to send a push notification, send it to the users corresponding to your list of sessions IDs

## Maintaining a collection of session IDs

Using a *map* to maintain the collections of connected clients may be more practical for your use case.

```js
const sessionsMap = {};

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  const sessionId = socket.id;

  socket.emit('askForJWT');

  socket.on('receivedJWT', (jwt) => {
    if (isValid(jwt)) {
      const userId = extractUserIdFromJWT(jwt);
      sessionsMap[sessionId] = userId;
    }
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    delete sessionsMap[sessionId];
  });
});
```

## Sending the notification

Iterate over the values inside the map to send them (using your API of choice) the notification.

```js
function sendNotification(message) {
  const listOfUsersIds = Object.values(sessionsMap);

  listOfUsersIds.forEach((userId) => {
    // Here you send the notification with your API of choice
    api.send({message, userId});
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer .. the issue I have with this solution is that it assumes that the application will be running so that it receives the socket notification and replies with the JWT -- however, in practice a push notification can be sent while the application is not running at all. When the application is closed the user didn't necessarily log out

Comment: You can send a push notification even if the app is closed, that's true. But for a user to be **currenyly** logged in, the app need to be active/open. Similarly the app can be closed even if the JWT is still valid (authenticated user), but then the user won't be **currently** logged in